# Why is there no output when using controllerAs in AngualrJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I expect that there will be an "Hello World!" in the output of `ctrl.hellos`,but I get nothing.

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl" ng-bind="ctrl.hellos"></div>
</div>
<script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.provider('helloWorld', function() {
        var _name = 'Default';

        this.$get = function($q) {
            return {
                sayHello: function() {
                    var deferred  = $q.defer()
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        if (_name !== 'Default') {
                            deferred.resolve('Hello, ' + _name + '!');
                        } else {
                            deferred.reject('No changes');
                        }
                    }, 3000);
                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            }
        };
        this.setName = function(newName) {
            _name = newName;
        }
    });


    myApp.config(function(helloWorldProvider){
        helloWorldProvider.setName('World');
    });

    myApp.controller('MyCtrl',['helloWorld',myCtrl]);

    function myCtrl(helloWorld) {
        helloWorld.sayHello().then(function(text){
            this.hellos = text
        },function(msg){
            this.hellos = msg
        })
    }
</script>
```

Is there anything wrong in the code?thanks

Comment: First, try to debug and see if your call get a result in the success or error function. You can also try to put `ng-controller="..."` on the same `div` than `ng-app="myApp"`

Comment: Have you debugged in your js code? like try console.log(ctrl.hellos) to print if it get correct data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue your having is defined in the [Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-20).

Primarily here:

> onFulfilled and onRejected must be called as functions (i.e. with no this value).

As angular's form of promises conforms to that standard your `onFulfilled` has the context set to the `window` object, similar to `setTimeout`/`setInterval` etc.

You have a couple of options.

Alias the `this`, `.bind` your callback or use ES2015 arrow functions which will apply the calling context. (Similar result to using`.bind`)

```
    // alias
    var self = this;
    helloWorld.sayHello().then(function(text){
        self.hellos = text
    },function(msg){
        self.hellos = msg
    });

    // bind
    helloWorld.sayHello().then(function(text){
        this.hellos = text
    }.bind(this),function(msg){
        this.hellos = msg
    }.bind(this));

    // Arrow function
    helloWorld.sayHello().then((text) => {
        this.hellos = text
    },(msg) => {
        this.hellos = msg
    });
```

[Arrow function example](https://jsfiddle.net/y439xsLn/1/)

---

Just FYI on the use of `ngBind`

> Typically, you don't use ngBind directly, but instead you use the double curly markup like {{ expression }} which is similar but less verbose.

From [Angular's docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely.It's very helpful and knowledgeable

Answer (score 0):

change your controller function

```
function myCtrl(helloWorld) {
   var ctrl = this
    helloWorld.sayHello().then(function(text){
        ctrl.hellos = text
    },function(msg){
        ctrl.hellos = msg
    })
}
```

and in your html

`<h1>{{ctrl.hellos}}</h1>`